# Tracking e-mail link clicking

Tags: 2013

I am Unable to Track the links and redirect to the specific url.

I am using the Function

```
<a href="@@GetLinkTrackingURL('http://www.google.com','Google')@@">Google</a>
```

GetLinkTrackingURL function is not working ,And i dont want to hard code this value like google link I need to fetch the Internal link like this :

```
<a href="@@GetLinkTrackingURL(Component.ID,Component.Title)@@">abc</a>
```

Please Help me Through This.

Comment: It looks like your code examples got scrambled. Can you make sure we can all read the code?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'not working'. Do you get an error? Is it not transformed to a temporary instruction in the template? When do you see the problem -- in the template, or the test e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that "Outbound Email Post Processing" TBB has been attached to the Compound Page Template.

This TBB should be there before Default Finish Actions TBB in the list.

Also check if TrackingPage path has been correctly configured in the publication's properties.